# Render rails partial multiple times on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, render

I have a partial that I'm rendering twice on the same page, but in two different locations (one is shown during standard layout, one is shown during mobile/tablet layout).

The partial is rendered exactly the same in both places, so I'd like to speed it up by storing it as a variable if possible; the partial makes an API call each time, and the 2nd call is completely unnecessary since it's a duplicate of the first API call.

Is there any way to store the HTML from the returned partial as a variable and then use that for both renders?

**Edit:** I'm hoping to do this without caching, as it is a very simple need and I'm looking to keep the codebase lean and readable.  Is it possible to store the partial as a string variable and then reference that twice?

Comment: Have you consider just using fragment caching (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html).  If you are caching the same fragment, the cache call will stop the execution from occurring twice.

Comment: Hi Rob, see my edit above; I'm hoping to do this without caching if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use fragment caching. After you wrap the partial with a cache block, the second call should show the cached version of the first. For example:

```
<% cache do %>
  <%= render(:partial => 'my_partial') %>
<% end %>

... later in the same view ...

<% cache do %>
  <%= render(:partial => 'my_partial') %>
<% end %>
```

To store the result of the render to a string, you could try the `render_to_string` method of `AbstractController`. The arguments are the same as for `render`.

```
partial_string = render_to_string(:partial => 'my_partial')
```

Comment: I am familiar with fragment caching, but hoping to do this in a much simpler way (no need for sweepers, etc).  The end HTML from the partial could be captured as a string variable and then simply rendered twice as such.

Comment: I added another way if you want to take a look.

Comment: This works in the controller [  render_to_string(:partial => 'my_partial', :locals => {:my_object => my_value})  ], but it takes about twice as long as simply making the API call twice and rendering twice.  Any idea why?

Comment: Just basing it on the rough 200 OK times for 5-10 requests in development mode.  Render request is taking ~750ms, while render_to_string is taking ~1500ms.  Is there additional overhead when invoking AbstractController?

Answer (score 8):

```
<% content_for :example do %>
  <%= render :your_partial %>
<%end%>
```

then call `<%= yield :example %>` or `<%= content_for :example %>` wherever you want your partial called.

Comment: Calling yield twice will not make the API call twice?

Answer (score 1):

*I'm adding an answer to this old question because it topped Google for a search I just made.*

There's another way to do this now (for quite a while), the [capture helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture).

```
<% reuse_my_partial = capture do %>
  <%= render partial: "your_partial" %>
<% end %>

<div class="visible-on-desktop"
  <%= reuse_my_partial %>
</div>

<div class="visible-on-mobile"
  <%= reuse_my_partial %>
</div>
```

This is simpler and slightly safer than using content_for because there is no global storage involved that something else might modify.

The rails docs linked to use instance @vars instead of local vars because they want it to be available to their layout template. That's a detail you do not need to worry about, because you're using it in the same template file.